# How to partial update mongodb document in Web Api Patch request

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I want to partial update fileds of my document that  changed in the **patch request** and in every request the field **probably changed** for example one time Balance will be charged another time AccountHolder and others.
I want to update each specific field in single method not create a method for the number of fields .

Note: there is nothing in IDto interface, I use it just for separating Dtos from other classes.

UpdateAccountDto.cs

```
public class UpdateAccountDto : IDto
{
    public string Id { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string AccountId { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string AccountHolder { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string AccountType { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
}
```

Account.cs my entity

```
public class Account
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [BsonElement("account_id")] 
    public string AccountId { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [BsonElement("account_holder")]
    public string AccountHolder { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [BsonElement("account_type")]
    public string AccountType { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Decimal128)]
    [BsonElement("balance")]
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }

}
```

My endpoint

```
        [HttpPatch("UpdatePartialAccount")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> UpdatePartialAccount([FromQuery]string id,[FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<UpdateAccountDto>? document)
        {
            if (document is null)
                return BadRequest();

            var updateAccountDto = document.ToDto();

            document.ApplyTo(updateAccountDto, ModelState);

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest();

            var entity = updateAccountDto.ToEntity<Account>();
            entity.Id = id;

            await _accountRepository.PartialUpdateAsync(entity);

            return NoContent();

        }
```

PartialUpdateAsync method

```
   public async Task<UpdateResult> PartialUpdateAsync(Account account)
    {
        //var filter = Builders<Account>.Filter.Eq(a => a.Id, account.Id);
        //var update = Builders<Account>.Update.Set()
        //Partial update

        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question are actually not very clear, but I guess you may want to know the field settings corresponding to `JsonPatchDocument` and the operation of updating the `Mongodb` database.

Regarding the field setting of `JsonPatchDocument`, you can refer to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to use it. For example:

```
[HttpPatch("UpdatePartialAccount")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> UpdatePartialAccount([FromQuery] string id, [FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<UpdateAccountDto>? document)
{
    if (document is null)
        return BadRequest();

    var dto = new UpdateAccountDto() { AccountId = "DAccount1" };

    document.ApplyTo(dto, ModelState);
    //.....
}
```

Suppose you do a Replace operation on it:

```
[
  {
    "operationType": 2,
    "path": "/accountHolder",
    "op": "replace",
    "value": "TestHolder"
  }
]
```

At this point your `dto` will become:

[image]

Please confirm the content of `dto` and then match with Account to update the database(I'm not sure how you map to `Account`, but I used `AutoMapper`). For example:

```
public async Task UpdateAsync(Account account)
{
    await _account.UpdateOneAsync(c => c.AccountId == account.AccountId, account.AccountHolder);
}
```

For more operations on updating the database, you can check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58192298/c-sharp-driver-mongodb-how-to-use-updateoneasync).

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but There is no problem with Patch Request in the code, my problem is how to write a query that one time update AccountHolder, another time update Balance and other fields in a single method and not writing methods to update each fields of document using Mongodb C# driver and i used Automapper with my own extension methods like ToDto or ToEntity

Comment: Update different fields each execution in the same method? Maybe it is possible to monitor a certain state and add a judgment condition?